# Properly implement ItemSource for ListView

Tags: c++, xaml, listview, uwp, c++-cx

I tried implement a class that can be put as `ItemSource` for `ListView` following Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization) i.e. implementing `IObservableVector<T>` but as always, documentation never works and there is no C++ sample code to begin with. The content of my XAML for MainPage is just

```
<ListView x:Name="TestListView"/>
```

and the source code

```
public ref class MyStringSrc sealed : Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Platform::String^>
{
public:
    // Inherited via IVector
    virtual Windows::Foundation::Collections::IIterator<Platform::String ^> ^ First();

    // Inherited via IObservableVector
    virtual property unsigned int Size
    {
        unsigned int get()
        {
            return _size;
        }
    }
    virtual Platform::String ^ GetAt(unsigned int index);
    virtual Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Platform::String ^> ^ GetView();
    virtual bool IndexOf(Platform::String ^value, unsigned int *index);
    virtual void SetAt(unsigned int index, Platform::String ^value);
    virtual void InsertAt(unsigned int index, Platform::String ^value);
    virtual void RemoveAt(unsigned int index);
    virtual void Append(Platform::String ^value);
    virtual void RemoveAtEnd();
    virtual void Clear();
    virtual unsigned int GetMany(unsigned int startIndex, Platform::WriteOnlyArray<Platform::String ^, 1U> ^items);
    virtual void ReplaceAll(const Platform::Array<Platform::String ^, 1U> ^items);
    virtual event Windows::Foundation::Collections::VectorChangedEventHandler<Platform::String ^> ^ VectorChanged;
private:
    unsigned int _size = 1000;
};

public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();
};
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TestListView->ItemsSource = ref new MyStringSrc();
}

Windows::Foundation::Collections::IIterator<Platform::String ^> ^ MyStringSrc::First()
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
    // TODO: insert return statement here
}

Platform::String ^ MyStringSrc::GetAt(unsigned int index)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
    // TODO: insert return statement here
}

Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Platform::String ^> ^ MyStringSrc::GetView()
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
    // TODO: insert return statement here
}

bool MyStringSrc::IndexOf(Platform::String ^value, unsigned int *index)
{
    return false;
}

void MyStringSrc::SetAt(unsigned int index, Platform::String ^value)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

void MyStringSrc::InsertAt(unsigned int index, Platform::String ^value)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

void MyStringSrc::RemoveAt(unsigned int index)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

void MyStringSrc::Append(Platform::String ^value)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

void MyStringSrc::RemoveAtEnd()
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

void MyStringSrc::Clear()
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}

unsigned int MyStringSrc::GetMany(unsigned int startIndex, Platform::WriteOnlyArray<Platform::String ^, 1U> ^items)
{
    return 0;
}

void MyStringSrc::ReplaceAll(const Platform::Array<Platform::String ^, 1U> ^items)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}
```

When running the app, I always get

**Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::InvalidArgumentException ^ at memory location 0x02E2DA80. HRESULT:0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
WinRT information: The parameter is incorrect.**

right at the line where I set

```
TestListView->ItemsSource = ref new MyStringSrc();
```

Is there a sample implementation I can follow?

Comment: Do you specifically need a custom IObservableVector class instead of using something existing like [Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh441570.aspx)?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I don't actually know. I am trying to do incremental loading as in the article which suggests to implement `IObservableVector`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the documentation, you *MUST NOT* implement `IObservableVector`. What you must implement is `Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::IBindableObservableVector`. I found this in the Windows 8.1 XAML sample refers to in the article. (The documentation refers to the God forsaken Windows 8.1!) Unfortunately, I will lose all my generic code. Shouldn't started with generic when it comes to UI anyway.

Microsoft's documentation, as usual, always lacks the necessary degree of clarity. It never tells what kind of thing can be set as `ItemsSource`. By experimentation, it seems that it must be something under the `Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::IBindable*` umbrella.